# Make network stream available via Flash

Tags: flash, streaming, video-streaming

We have the following network stream http://zara.mitranet.cz:8080/

Users must install VLC to view it as a network stream. Can we provide the stream to them via Flash Player somehow? For example, is there some Flash Player proxy that would capture the stream and display it in a browser?

We don't want bother users with installing SW and/or codecs...

Comment: I guess the users would have to install flash though...

Comment: We can assume flash is almost everywhere today. Who doesn't watch youtube nowadays?

Comment: Uhm, I do. But that is because youtube broke for me a few months ago (on all computers, but from me and from guests. So it is probably an ISP routing issue).  But the real reason not to use flash is the constant stream of new bugs. So if you do not need flash then do not install it. And not everybody needs flash.